# Reading Huge excel File and Get Metadata Activity is Failing out of memory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

ystem.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.TasksCoordinator.CheckTaskFailureOrCancellation()
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PartitionParallelStageProcessor`1.Process(IEnumerable`1 data)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PipelineProcessStageProcessor`2.Process(TInput data) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.Provider.HybridRuntimeDataReader..ctor(HybridRuntimeCommand command, String commandBehavior, IMemoryLimit memoryLimit, Int32 previewCount) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.Provider.HybridRuntimeCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(String commandBehavior, Int32 rowCount) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.GetMetadataWorker.HandleStructureFields(IList`1 fieldList, InnerPropertyBags innerPropertyBags, HybridRuntimeConnection connection, IDictionary`2 metadata) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.GetMetadataWorker.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<GetMetadata>b__1() at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.GetMetadataWorker.HybridDeliveryExceptionToExecutionException(Action action) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.GetMetadataWorker.GetMetadata(InnerPropertyBags innerPropertyBags, GetMetadataProperties getMetadataProperties) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.GetMetadataWorker.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionParameters executionParameters, IProgress`1 progress, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Execution.RuntimeTask.ExecutionTask.Execute()

Please help how to resolve this???

Comment: Can you add your pipeline flow and configurations for better understanding?

Comment: I am just passing Inputfile name as aparameter and it is event based trigger..pipeline is failing at first activity Getmeatdata..GetMetadata activity is reading only structure of excel file.Not sure why memory exception

Comment: Ok, can you add error image of the pipeline?

Comment: Same error mentioned above

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-capabilities),

> There is a limitation of 4 MB for the output meta data that is returned by the Get Meta data activity in ADF. If the data limit exceeds this number, there is a chance that it may give the out of memory error.

As you mentioned that your excel fie is huge, it might be the reason for the Out of memory error where the `structure` output exceeded the limit of 4 MB.

Here, you can see that I am able to get the structure, when my excel file size is less.

[image]

So, you cannot get the structure of the excel file using Get Meta data activity if the excel file size is huge. Try with databricks or Azure functions to get the schema or structure of the excel file and that might be the workaround here.

Comment: Thank you.. Databricks i can't use at this point in time.  Do you have material how to do with azurefunction???

Comment: You can read the Excel file as pandas dataframe by following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664384/azure-function-read-xlsx-from-azure-blob, then get the schema of the dataframe https://www.codeease.net/programming/python/print-schema-in-pandas-dataframe and return it in the Azure function. To get the output in ADF, Use Azure function activity and call it from ADF.